# Uvicorn backlog vs limit-concurrency

Tags: uvicorn, asgi

I'm trying to understand the interaction between the "backlog" flag, and the "limit-concurrency" flag of uvicorn. From the documentation(https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/)

Backlog:
Maximum number of connections to hold in backlog. Relevant for heavy incoming traffic. Default: 2048

limit-concurrency:
Maximum number of concurrent connections or tasks to allow, before issuing HTTP 503 responses. Useful for ensuring known memory usage patterns even under over-resourced loads.

Both of these descriptions seem to make sense independently, depending how you interpret the word "backlog". But I'm confused at how they interact with eachother.

Limit-concurrency explicitly says that if you exceed that number of open connections then it will throw a 503 error, but the backlog defaulting to 2048 seems to imply to me that uvicorn will hold 2048 requests waiting for other requests to complete, which means that it wouldn't be 503ing.

Can anyone shed light on these settings?

Answer (score 1):

There is no interaction between the 2 flags.

`backlog` is passed down the `loop.create_server` and ultimately will determine the number of sockets listening.

`limit-concurrency` is just here to tell, after x responses issue a 503

Comment: How do you ever get to 1000 backlogged connections if limit concurrency is at 5 for example?

Answer (score 0):

[`--backlog`](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#backlog)

> The maximum number of pending connections.
>
> This refers to the number of clients that can be waiting to be served. Exceeding this number results in the client getting an error when attempting to connect. It should only affect servers under significant load.
>
> Must be a positive integer. Generally set in the 64-2048 range.

combine that with @siminchengithub's [answer](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/discussions/1817#discussioncomment-4503867), it looks like `--limit-concurrency` works on the task/thread level, and `--backlog` on the connection level:

> After reading the source code further, I think there is actually a bug.
> The `limit_concurrency` check is done inside `on_headers_complete` **after** a connection is added and **before** a new task is added. This will work correctly to make sure any extra requests receive 503. However this won't make sure there are less than `limit_concurrency` connections. Connections can continue to pile up as long as they are not closed.